# Add value to Hashtable using lambda

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, hashmap, hashtable

Fist of all, I'm pretty new to Java my approach to the problem might not be optimal.

I have some lists of strings, say `{"a", "b", "e", "g"}` and `{"no", "a", "g", "great"}`, which contain **4 items** each from a set of values.

I want to create a `Hashtable` of that set, **assigning** an `int` value to each `String`. For a specific `String`, I want to use a **lambda expression** to assign **different values** to it **based on** the **other items** in the list it's contained in, something like:

```
class bla {
    static Map stuff;
    static {
        // If I write it like this, I get the error "Cannot resolve method ContainsAll"
         stuff.put("g", (aList) -> (aList.containsAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e", "g")) ? 1 : 2)); 
    }
}
```

If I add a `List<String>` to `(aList)` like so, `(List <String> aList)` then I get, a "*Target type of a lambda expression must be an interface*" error.

If I replace `()` with `{}` for the lambda body, I get the "*; expected error*".

How can I write this to work? Or, do you have a better idea?

Comment: You seem to be trying random things instead of reading the javadoc of the classes you're using. First hint: No method in the JDK ever starts with an uppercase letter.

Comment: ^ and you almost certainly won’t need a lambda to do what you want.

Comment: Also, don't use raw types. Your want a Map<SomeKeyType, SomeValueType>. Not a Map.

Comment: *"`if i write it like this, i get the error Cannot resolve method ContainsAll`"* according the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) method names start with a *lower case* letter...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't get what exactly you want to map, what determines the `int` values? It seems that you are struggling more with the basics and not your specific problems. Maybe you should first read some tutorial on how those things work before you try to solve your issue. Then you might understand why the compiler complaints. And also how you can rewrite your code to a more suitable format.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

Oh, and you want a `Map<String,Integer>`, not a `Hashtable`. `Hashtable` is not deprecated, but very bad and slow for most of your use-cases.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = Stream.of("no", "a", "g", "great")
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        x -> Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e", "g").contains(x) ? 1 : 2
      ));
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{a=1, no=2, g=1, great=2}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I haven't made myself clear. So, I have a bunch of strings i want to use as keys in a HashMap where i assign values to them. I also have some lists of a fixed number of those strings, say 4 and from these i want to create new lists of integers based on the values in the HashMap. One or more of strings will need to have assigned different values if they are part of a specific list(is made of certain strings, not in any kind of order). I hope this made it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.. finally. I know the code I posted was more of a idea of i wanted and i was focused on this line:

```
stuff.put("g", (aList) -> (aList.containsAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e", "g")) ? 1 : 2));
```

I realized the HashMap needs to be defined as Map(String, InterfaceName) and not (String, Integer):

```
interface Something{
    int doStuff(List<String> blabla);
}

class bla{
    static Map<String, Something> stuff;
    static{
        stuff = new HashMap<>();
        stuff.put("a", (List<String> aList) -> 30); 
        stuff.put("g", (List<String> aList) -> aList.containsAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e", "g")) ? 10 : 25); // I only need this for a few of the strings
    }
}
```